# tolower function for C++ strings

Tags: c++, tolower

Is there an inbuilt function to convert C++ string from upper case letters to lowercase letters ? If not converting it to cstring and using tolower on each char is the only option ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In Germany, tolower("STRASSE") should result in "straße". In Swiss, it should be "strasse". And there are many more cases like this around the world. An inbuilt function must correctly handle those cases. If you don't care, just use tolower() on each character as most answers show.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Nice example. Have you heard of any library that deals with those cases gracefully ? I could be interested in it.

Comment: @ereOn: No, I never needed one. I know there are problems with tolower() but where I live and in the applications I write, tolower() usually is "good enough".

Comment: I'd imagine ICU can handle it correctly (http://icu-project.org/), but it might be overkill for the OP's purposes.

Comment: @ereOn: it is actually near impossible without a dictionary that contains all ambiguous words. In german, SS is only ß if spoken slowly, otherwise it should become ss.

Comment: @Jalf: Does ICU come with dictionaries? In German, for an instance, there is no 1-to-1 mapping of `SS -> lowercase`; e.g.  `STRASSE -> straße`, but `TRASSE -> trasse`. Some words are not even unambiguous: `MASSE -> maße` (= measures, dimensions) and `MASSE -> masse` (= mass).  (edit: I realise just now that I already visited this question in the past, xd)

Comment: @phresnel: honestly? I don't know how (or if) this case is handled. ICU just follows Unicode's rules, and I don't know what the Unicode standard has to say about this case.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If `boost` is an option:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>    

std::string str = "wHatEver";
boost::to_lower(str);
```

Otherwise, you may use `std::transform`:

```
std::string str = "wHatEver";
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

You can also use another function if you have some custom locale-aware `tolower`.

Comment: Note that [according to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower), a call to `tolower` with a parameter that can't be cast to `unsigned char` results in UB. So what you probably want is something like: `std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });`

Answer (score 22):

```
std::transform(myString.begin(), myString.end(), myString.begin(), std::tolower);
```

Comment: This and other transform + tolower answers should take into account that this won't necessarily compile, depending on what standard headers are included in this file. There is one `tolower` in `<cctype>` and an overload in `<locale>`. If both get included, you'll get a compiler error. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350380/problems-using-stl-stdtransform-from-cygwin-g

Comment: Note that this answer (and all of the other `transform` answers) potentially cause undefined behaviour, because `cstdlib`'s `std::tolower` requires a non-negative argument

Answer (score 2):

Like ereOn says:
`std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::tolower );`

Or via for_each:
`std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), std::tolower );`

Transform is probably better of the two.

Comment: I bet so. for_each does not change str.

Comment: It was written off the cuff.  You could use a lamda to call tolower for each character.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem you can use the STL's transform method to solve it:

```
std::string str = "simple";
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::tolower);
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers produced errors.
This works perfectly:

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to do this, and doing it is surprisingly complicated, because of locales et al. If `tolower` does what you need, it may be your best bet.

Answer (score -2):

I have an implementation I found it faster than std::transform , Compiled in g++ -03 Fedora 18. my example converts std::string

```
performance time in seconds :
transform took         : 11 s
my implementation took : 2 s
Test data size = 26*15*9999999 chars
```

```
inline void tolowerPtr(char *p) ;

inline void tolowerStr(std::string& s)
{char* c=const_cast<char*>(s.c_str());
size_t l = s.size();
  for(char* c2=c;c2<c+l;c2++)tolowerPtr(c2); 
};

inline void tolowerPtr(char *p) 
{
switch(*p)
{
  case 'A':*p='a'; return;
  case 'B':*p='b'; return;
  case 'C':*p='c'; return;
  case 'D':*p='d'; return;
  case 'E':*p='e'; return;
  case 'F':*p='f'; return;
  case 'G':*p='g'; return;
  case 'H':*p='h'; return;
  case 'I':*p='i'; return;
  case 'J':*p='j'; return;
  case 'K':*p='k'; return;
  case 'L':*p='l'; return;
  case 'M':*p='m'; return;
  case 'N':*p='n'; return;
  case 'O':*p='o'; return;
  case 'P':*p='p'; return;
  case 'Q':*p='q'; return;
  case 'R':*p='r'; return;
  case 'S':*p='s'; return;
  case 'T':*p='t'; return;
  case 'U':*p='u'; return;
  case 'V':*p='v'; return;
  case 'W':*p='w'; return;
  case 'X':*p='x'; return;
  case 'Y':*p='y'; return;
  case 'Z':*p='z'; return;
};
return ;
}

void testtransform( std::string& word )
{
std::string word2=word; 
time_t t;
time_t t2;
time(&t);
std::cout << "testtransform: start " << "\n";
int i=0;
for(;i<9999999;i++) 
{    word2=word;
    std::transform(word2.begin(), word2.end(), word2.begin(), ::tolower);
}
time(&t2);
std::cout << word2 << "\n";
std::cout << "testtransform: end " << i << ":"<< t2-t << "\n";
}

void testmytolower( std::string& word )
{
std::string word2=word; 
time_t t;
time_t t2;
time(&t);
std::cout << "testmytolower: start " << "\n";
int i=0;
for(;i<9999999;i++)
{   word2=word;
    cstralgo::tolowerStr(word2);
}
time(&t2);
std::cout << word2 << "\n";
std::cout << "testmytolower: end " << i << ":"<< t2-t << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::string word ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   word =word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word+word;
   testtransform( word);
   testmytolower( word);
   return 0;
}
```

I will be glad to know if performance can be improved further.

Comment: You are just covering ASCII alphabet here, and in a quite horrible way. The same can be achieved by: `if (*p >= 'A' && *p <=Z) *p += 'a' - 'A'`. And you are still potentially missing many other letters e.g. 'Á'.

Comment: Your test has a problem. Run it on a long random word I generated mine with `cat /dev/urandom | LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc '[:alpha:]' | fold -w ${1:-100000000} | head -n 1`, and you function is only a bit (10% faster than transform).
Use the suggested `if (*p >= 'A' && *p <=Z) *p += 'a' - 'A'` and get 45-48% faster.
Pass the char parameter by reference (not pinter) and get an additional 5% faster.