# Basic C++ calculator

Tags: c++, if-statement, calculator

I'm quite new to C++. This is what I'm disposing with at the moment and I suppose you can guess the logic I'm trying to apply to the program so that it may work. I need the user to supply an arithmetic to be performed and if it's a certain one to add the numbers together. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int v;
    int sum;
    string input;
    cout << "Choose arithmetic: addition or subtraction? " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if(input=='Addition'||input=='addition')
    {
        int first;
        int second;
        int sum = first+second;
        cout << "Enter the first number: " << endl;
        cout << "Enter the second number: " << endl;
        cout << "The sum of these numbers is: " << sum << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives me the following error:
**13 error: no match for 'operator==' in 'input == 1953066862'**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Based on the other code you have there and the line the error references, you should be able to spot the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literal strings in C++ use *double quotes*, not single quotes. That is, `"Addition"` instead of `'Addition'`.

A single-quoted string is something called a "multi-character constant" which is valid but definitely not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, a string should be in "" rather than ''. It should be `"Addition"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotation marks (") instead of single quotation marks (') on the following line:

`if(input=='Addition'||input=='addition')`

Answer (score 0):

In C++, literal/constant character strings are wrapped in double quotes (e.g. "string"). Literal/constant single characters are wrapped in single quotes ('c').

As it's good programming practice, you may also want to convert your user's input to lowercase and then perform the conditional (use the function tolower()). That way you can cover all upper/lower case permutations :).

[tolower function for C++ strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403844/tolower-function-for-c-strings)

Answer (score 0):

u can use just an operator, check this out:

http://www.programmingtunes.com/a-simple-calculator-in-c/

you just enter your complete statement here and get your answer.
eg: 5+6